# Trouble with SSL when loading resources on my Rpi

Tags: c#, ssl, nginx, asp.net-core-2.0

I am using Asp.Net Core on my Raspbian.

I am using NGINX as my web Server

I trying to load resource and connect to my web api controller

The trouble is that my uri's are being changed from http to https.

As I want to browser to this site elsewhere on my network I am very limited as to what I can achieve. If I am on the Pi itself and use localhost or 127.0.0.1 then everything loads OK.  If I access it using the dhcp address it fails.

It works because I am using Open SSL but only on the local level.

This is my NGINX:

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;

# SSL configuration
#
# listen 443 ssl default_server;
# listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
#
# Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
# See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
#
# Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
# See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
#
# Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
# Don't use them in a production server!
#
# include snippets/snakeoil.conf;
    listen               443;
    ssl                  on;
    ssl_certificate      /home/pi/web/localhost.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /home/pi/web/localhost.key;
    ssl_ciphers          HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;


root /var/www/html;

# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name _;






location /FindMotion/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host   $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  http;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Path   /FindMotion;
}
}
```

This my Javascript:

```
var timer;
function RenderImage() {
    try {

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Connection/ImageData",
            success: function(response) {
                var image = new Image();
                image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,' +response;
                document.body.appendChild(image);
                timer = setTimeout(function() { RenderImage(); }, 10000);
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $("#divImage").html("ERROR: " + errorThrown);
                timer = setTimeout(function() { RenderImage(); }, 10000);
            }
        });
    } catch (err) {
        $("#divImage").html(err);
        timer = setTimeout(function() { RenderImage(); }, 10000);
    }
}

RenderImage();
```

This is my controller:

```
[ HttpGet ]
[ Route( "Connection/ImageData" ) ]
public string GetImageData()
{
    var img = new Bitmap( "20190521141101456.jpg" );

    using ( MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream() )
    {       
            img.Save( mStream, img.RawFormat );
            var bytes = mStream.ToArray();
            var data = Convert.ToBase64String( bytes );
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

The error in the browsing console is:
    https://192.168.0.12/Connection/ImageData 404 (Not Found)

Am I correct in thinking this cannot work because the Open SSL is not adequate?

And if so am I also correct in thinking that I would have to get a 'proper' SSL and I would need a domain name for this?

If that is the case, for every product I sell/produce I would need a domain and static address for each one?

Have I got this completely wrong or right?  What are my options please?  I have tried a lot of things over the last few days and nothing works.

I desperately need advice please.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is more likely an nginx configuration problem. 404 not found would suggest there is nothing on 403. Not that the TSL version or SSL version does not work out for you. You would probably get a 400 (Bad Request) or 495 (SSL Error) from nginx.

Try it like this. I´m not sure about that. But I have never seen both http and https configured in the same block. Now I´m not a sysadmin far from it, but my own servers are set up more like this. I also put a line ssl_protocols in there to specify basically all of them. Maybe that that helps. But as I said I don´t think it would be an TLS or SSL problem when you get back 404.

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;
return 301 https://192.168.0.12$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen               443;
    ssl                  on;
    ssl_certificate      /home/pi/web/localhost.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /home/pi/web/localhost.key;
    ssl_ciphers          HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

root /var/www/html;

# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name _;


location /FindMotion/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host   $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  http;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Path   /FindMotion;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing that.  I had to triple check it worked and it did!  Just came down to nginx config.  IfI could give you 2 ticks I would!  NowI just need to get web sockets working.

Comment: Thanks, glad it worked. :) With websockets I can't immidiately spit out a solution, since the only times I've used those are at work with azure. And there you have a "make it work" checkbox (enable websockets).